# A way to get the value of os.Error - string value (Go)

Tags: go

How do I get the string value of *os.Error*?

That is, assign to a variable.

Comment: you should accept a few answers to your questions. It will encourage *further* answers.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    err := errors.New("an error message")
    s := err.Error()
    fmt.Printf("type: %T; value: %q\n", s, s)
}
```

Output:

```
type: string; value: "an error message"
```

Documentation with a full list of fmt formatting verbs,

[fmt package's format verbs](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Printing)

Answer (score 40):

Based on [go1 release notes](http://golang.org/doc/go1.html#errors):

**Use err.Error() to get the string value.**

### Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    err := errors.New("use of err.String() detected!")
    s := err.Error()
    fmt.Printf(
       "version: %s\ntypes: %T / %T\nstring value via err.Error(): %q\n",
       runtime.Version(), err, s, s)
}
```

Output:

```
go run main102.go
version: go1.0.2
types: *errors.errorString / string
string value via err.Error(): "use of err.String() detected!"
```

Comment: Thank you! I use `err.Error()` that'd be nice !

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `fmt.Sprint(err)`

This returns a variable of type string which you can then, for instance, assign to a variable:

`message := fmt.Sprint(err)`