# How can I get an error message in a string in Go?

Tags: go

I referred to this question, *[A way to get the value of os.Error - string value (Go)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012692/os-error-string-value-golang)*, but that is not working in my case.

```
func (t Trans) TicketQty() (intQty int, err string) {
  defer func() {
    str := recover()
    if(str != nil){
      err = "an error"
    }
  }()
  Qty := t.TransObject["qty"].(map[string] interface{})["ticket fv"].(float64)
  intQty = 10
  return
}
```

In that `err`, I need the error message that is thrown, e.g., if the parsing logic fails, it is throwing an error automatically. That is the error I need to catch. I am showing this only for example - whatever the runtime exception is, I need to catch it and pass as `err` in the return.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Code like `t.TransObject["qty"].(map[string] interface{})["ticket fv"].(float64)` points to some significant issue with modeling the domain properly. Maybe you could try a solution without empty interfaces and type assertions that wouldn't need lots of panic/defer/recover magic?

Comment: Just to add: it's not good practice to return errors as strings. Create your own error type `type MyError error` and give it a method: `func (m *MyError) Error() string` - this is all it needs to satisfy the `error` interface. Read this for more: blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Use the [`errors`](http://golang.org/pkg/errors) package to create new errors.

```
err = errors.New("an error")
```

The returned error can be treated as a string by either accessing `err.Error()`, or using the `fmt` package functions (for example `fmt.Println(err)`).

Don't use `recover` unless you *really know what you're doing*. It's idiomatic to return all errors, and to deal with them when they arise.

See [Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go), and [Defer, Panic and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) on the Go blog for more info.

Rereading your question, it looks like you're trying to recover from possible failed [type assertions](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions). In this instance it's recommended to use the "comma, ok" idiom (mentioned in the previously linked section of the docs), which (slightly paraphrased to be more general) means:

> "If the type assertion fails, [the receiver variable] will still exist and be of type [whatever was asserted], but it will have the zero value..."

A simple example to test if an `interface{}` is actually a `float64` through type assertion, and produce a custom error if it fails (instead of panicking):

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

// assertFloat64 attempts a type assertion to float64.
// It returns a custom error if it fails.
func assertFloat64(n interface{}) error {
    // Type assertion. Is n float64?
    f, ok := n.(float64)
    // If yes,
    if ok {
        // print the result
        fmt.Printf("%f is float64\n", f)
        // and return nil error.
        return nil
    }
    // Else return our custom error
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("could not assert that \"%v\" is float64.\n", n))
}

func main() {
    // Successful
    // 1024.0 is float64
    err := assertFloat64(1024.0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Failure
    // "foo" isn't float64
    err = assertFloat64("foo")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Will print:

> 1024.000000 is float64
> could not assert that "foo" is float64.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_NWaWFhNt2)

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I will create errors what u say its fine.
In some cases if i need recover means in that how i will get error in a string ?
My requirement is to log the error generated by system. please sugest me any idea for that.

Comment: @shan `error` is an [interface that implements `Error() string`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors). Call this method it to retrieve the message. Alternatively, the `fmt` package can process `error` values and prints the message automatically, so you can simply use `fmt.Println(err)` to print the message.

Comment: @nemo actually if i tried str.Error() it says that `str.Error undefined (type interface {} has no field or method Error)
` this error. sorry i m not able to figure out..

Comment: Problem is that str is a recover object.So its not coming i guess.I am very new to this language and messed up.

Comment: `str` is an `error` object, and it has a method called `Error()` that is its string representation.

Comment: BTW it's worth noting that `error` is an interface, not an object type. You can create custom error objects with internal data you may want to pass around in your app.

Comment: @shan `recover` gives you a `interface{}` value, a value that can hold any value. You have to assert whether the value implements the `error` interface. After that you can call `Error()` on it. See [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Answer (score 23):

I think this would do what you want:

```
func (t Trans) TicketQty() (intQty int, err error) {
  defer func() {    
    ex := recover()
    if(ex != nil){     
      // "%v" prints the value of ex
      // for strings, it is the string, for errors .Error() method, for Stringer the .String() etc
      // Errorf returns an error instead of a string
      err = fmt.Errorf("%v", ex)
    }
  }()   
  ... // do your thing
  return
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Adding to [@intermernet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171548/8961316), if you are creating custom error messages using `errors.New()`, you might want to keep a check out for the specific error message created. Additionally any other kind of error messages too can be checked in the same manner. Just use the `fmt.Sprintf()` function with `strings.Contains()`.

You can do this very simply:

```golang
if fmt.Sprint(err) == "My Custom Error" {
    // do something
}
```

Or better use `strings.Contains()`:

```golang
if strings.Contains(fmt.Sprint(err), "Custom Error") {
    // do something
}
```

**NOTE**: You can also use `err.Error()` which returns a string representation of the error instead of `fmt.Sprint(err)`.